# Is it possible to trigger a download before sending the 200 status in NodeJs and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Long story short, I want to return a downloaded file and some information regarding the file to use it later in Front-End in a response from a POST petition, this is what I have

I'm using a success flag to see if there's nothing wrong with the file processing function, if the flag is true, i have to redirect to another page after downloading the file, otherwise display an error message.

response method on server side

```
res.download(pathofile)
res.status(200).send({
     success: true,
     message: "File processed Correctly!",
     filename: filename,
     numberoflines: numberoflines
})
```

client-side

```
///Call to POST petition
if(res.success){
  console.log(filename)
  console.log(numberoflines)
  alert(res.message)
}
//Do something with values...
```

However, after the petition ,the client side only detects the body of the response function (I'm getting the filename and numberoflines from server) and not the downloaded file. I would like to know if it is possible to send both parts of the information (the values and the file) in one response or if a have to do something else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be logging `res.filename` and `res.numberoflines`

Comment: You can't send a regular response and a file download in the same request response.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax for workarounds.

Comment: I see, so, i have to either trigger the download or send the information of the response, right?

Comment: Right. See the linked question. A common approach is for the response to include a URL to open in a new window or iframe, and that URL performs the download.